# Cannot import sage.finance from sage-python

Tags: python, importerror, sage

When running `sage`, I can import `sage.finance` with no issues. However, when running `sage -python` (or `sage -ipython`), importing `sage.finance` brings the following traceback:

```
>>> import sage.finance 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                      
  File "/usr/lib/sagemath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/finance/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import all          
  File "/usr/lib/sagemath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/finance/all.py", line 1, in <module>
    from stock import Stock
  File "/usr/lib/sagemath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/finance/stock.py", line 20, in <module>
    from sage.structure.all import Sequence
  File "/usr/lib/sagemath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/structure/all.py", line 1, in <module>
    from factorization import Factorization
  File "/usr/lib/sagemath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/structure/factorization.py", line 187, in <module>
    from sage.rings.integer import Integer
  File "integer.pyx", line 1, in init sage.rings.integer (sage/rings/integer.c:38248)
  File "morphism.pyx", line 1, in init sage.categories.morphism (sage/categories/morphism.c:7490)
  File "map.pyx", line 1, in init sage.categories.map (sage/categories/map.c:8604)
  File "parent.pxd", line 12, in init sage.structure.element (sage/structure/element.c:31286)
  File "map.pxd", line 4, in init sage.structure.parent (sage/structure/parent.c:24406)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Map'
```

Any idea what can lead to this error, and how can I import the finance module from within `sage -python`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can import things directly, but only from `sage.all`, when not in the Sage shell.  Sage imports a *lot* of stuff.  Try this.

```
$ sage -ipython
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct  7 2013, 07:44:02) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from sage.all import finance

In [2]: finance.[tab]
finance.MarkovSwitchingMultifractal
finance.Stock
finance.TimeSeries
finance.autoregressive_fit
finance.black_scholes
finance.fractional_brownian_motion_simulation
finance.fractional_gaussian_noise_simulation
finance.lazy_import
finance.multifractal_cascade_random_walk_simulation
finance.stationary_gaussian_simulation
```